# CSS pseudo-element confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm puzzled how to work out this problem, which has a practical structure like so:

```
<p.lead><div.fa>[font-awsome-icon]</div> Orange Header Text </p>
<p.description> lorem ipsum... </p>
```

Using this CSS, I need to preserve the line reaching the circle, even if the orange `p.lead` text has to wrap.

```
  p.lead {
    position: relative;
    color: $erisaOrange;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px $darkCanvas;
    letter-spacing: 105%;
    margin-left: 8px;
    .fa {
      position: relative;
      top: 2px;
      left: -10px;
      margin-right: 0.3em;
      color: $darkerGray;
      text-shadow: 2px 2px $darkGray;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: transparent;
      content: '';
      border: 2px solid $darkGray;
      font-size: 114%;
      line-height: 44px;
      width: 44px;
      height: 44px;
      border-radius: 22px;
    }
  }

  p.description {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    margin-left: 19px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-left: 2px solid $darkGray;
    &:before {
      position: absolute;
      top: -1em;
      left: -2px;
      content: '';
      border-left: 2px solid $darkGray;
      height: 1em;
    }
    &:after {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -2.2em;
      left: -2px;
      content: '';
      border-left: 2px solid $darkGray;
      height: 2.2em;
    }
  }
}
```

As is (unacceptable). I don't need a "pure" css solution, necessarily.

[image]

Comment: Looks like your element is not wide enough to keep the text on a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this by structuring the HTML differently. No JS needed.

Having the icon and the header text in the same line will be inherently problematic. When the header text wraps, it's going to start again at the beginning of the line, exactly as you have demonstrated.

First, I would wrap the whole thing in a wrapper div and use that to create the 2px left border instead of using :before elements.

Then I would pull the icon div out of the p element. It would instead be  inside the wrapper div. I would position it absolutely to overlap the wrapper div's left border.

I would use a header (like an h2) instead of a p for the section header, but that's not necessary to make this work.

```css
h2.lead {
  position: relative;
  color: orange;
  font-size:24px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px grey;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.wrapper {
  position:relative;
  border-left: 2px solid gray;
  margin: 20px;
  padding:20px;
  width: 350px
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: -25px;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
  color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height:1;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  padding:0px;
  background-color:#fff;
}

p.description {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="icon">✪</div> 
  <h2 class="lead"> Here's some header text.
  Orange Header Text </h2>
  <p class="description"> lorem ipsum... </p>  
</div>
```

Comment: How do you program that code snippet in the answer?? (Thanks btw!)

Comment: @TideLake - when you're writing a question or answer, there's a toolbar at the top with formatting buttons. One of them looks like this `{ }`. That button opens a code snippet creator similar to jsfiddle. You're welcome! Glad it helped.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, it's really the button that looks like a page with a `</>` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the OP)*.

SOLUTION (with help from the accepted answer)

```
  .wrap-feature {
    position: relative;
    border-left: 2px solid $darkGray;
    margin: 0px 12px;
    &:after {
      position: absolute;
      content: ' ';
      left: -2px;
      bottom: -108px;
      line-height: 108px;
      height: 108px;
      border-left: 2px solid $darkGray;
    }
  }

  .icon {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    left: -25px;
    color: gray;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid $darkGray;
    font-size: 114%;
    line-height: 44px;
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    border-radius: 22px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#fff;
  }

  h5, p.description {
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
    margin-left: 26px;
  }

  h5 {
    color: $orange;
    letter-spacing: 105%;
    font-size: 22px;
  }

  p.description {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 2.2em;
  }
```